# Правильное использование потоков и базы данных

Tags: java, mysql

Люди советуют выводить запросы бд в отдельный поток.
Я этим ни разу не занимался, решил обратиться за помощью сюда.
Дайте пожалуйста примеры того как правильно нужно выводить запросы в отдельный поток.

Ведь по идее если выводить запрос в отдельный поток, неизвестно же когда придет ответ. А так как все у меня в главном потоке я думаю у меня будет проблема с информацией. Ведь я отправляю запрос тогда когда мне именно нужно получить данные из базы данных.

```
public class Infractions {
private int bans;
private int mutes;
private long banOn;
private long muteOn;
private long banEnd;
private long muteEnd;
private String player;
private String banCause;
private String muteCause;
private String banEnforcer;
private String muteEnforcer;

private Statement statement;

public Infractions(String player) {
    this.player = player;
    try {
        this.statement = Proxy.getInstance().getSql().getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet set = this.statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM infractions WHERE player_name = '" + this.player + "'");
        if (set.next()) {
            this.bans = set.getInt("bans");
            this.mutes = set.getInt("mutes");
            this.banOn = set.getLong("ban_on");
            this.muteOn = set.getLong("mute_on");
            this.banEnd = set.getLong("ban_end");
            this.muteEnd = set.getLong("mute_end");
            this.banCause = set.getString("ban_cause");
            this.muteCause = set.getString("mute_cause");
            this.banEnforcer = set.getString("ban_enforcer");
            this.muteEnforcer = set.getString("mute_enforcer");
        } else {
            this.bans = 0;
            this.mutes = 0;
            this.banOn = 0L;
            this.muteOn = 0L;
            this.banEnd = 0L;
            this.muteEnd = 0L;
            this.banCause = "unknown";
            this.muteCause = "unknown";
            this.banEnforcer = "unknown";
            this.muteEnforcer = "unknown";
            this.updateInfractions();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updateInfractions() {
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO infractions VALUES ('player_name', bans, mutes, ban_on, mute_on, 'ban_end', mute_end, 'ban_cause', 'mute_cause', 'ban_enforcer', 'mute_enforcer') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE player_name='" + this.player + "', bans=" + this.bans + ", mutes=" + this.mutes + ", ban_on=" + this.banOn + ", mute_on=" + this.muteOn + ", ban_end=" + this.banEnd + ", mute_end=" + this.muteEnd + ", ban_cause='" + this.banCause + "', mute_cause='" + this.muteCause + "', ban_enforcer='" + this.banEnforcer + "', mute_enforcer='" + this.muteEnforcer + "'");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updateBanInfo() {
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE infractions SET ban_cause='" + this.banCause + "', ban_enforcer='" + this.banEnforcer + "', ban_on=" + this.banOn + ",ban_end=" + this.banEnd + ", bans=" + this.bans + " WHERE player_name='" + this.player + "'");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updateMuteInfo() {
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE infractions SET mute_cause='" + this.muteCause + "', mute_enforcer='" + this.muteEnforcer + "', mute_on=" + this.muteOn + ", mute_end=" + this.muteEnd + ", mutes=" + this.mutes + " WHERE player_name='" + this.player + "'");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void unBan(boolean forcefully) {
    if (this.banEnd == 0L) {
        return;
    }
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() < this.banEnd) {
        this.bans = Math.max(0, this.bans - 1);
    }
    this.banEnd = 0L;
    this.banCause = "unknown";
    this.banEnforcer = "unknown";
    if (forcefully) {
        this.updateBanInfo();
    }
}

public void unMute(boolean forcefully) {
    if (this.muteEnd == 0L) {
        return;
    }
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() < this.muteEnd) {
        this.mutes = Math.max(0, this.mutes - 1);
    }
    this.muteEnd = 0L;
    this.muteCause = "unknown";
    this.muteEnforcer = "unknown";
    if (forcefully) {
        this.updateMuteInfo();
    }
}

public void ban(boolean forcefully, long end, String cause, String enforcer) {
    ++ this.bans;
    this.banEnd = end;
    this.banCause = cause;
    this.banEnforcer = enforcer;
    if (forcefully) {
        this.updateBanInfo();
    }
}

public void mute(boolean forcefully, long end, String cause, String enforcer) {
    ++ this.mutes;
    this.muteEnd = end;
    this.muteCause = cause;
    this.muteEnforcer = enforcer;
    if (forcefully) {
        this.updateMuteInfo();
    }
}

public void check() {
    if (isBanned()) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > banEnd) {
            this.banOn = 0L;
            this.banEnd = 0L;
            this.banCause = "unknown";
            this.banEnforcer = "unknown";
            updateBanInfo();
        }
    }
    if (isMuted()) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > muteEnd) {
            this.muteOn = 0L;
            this.muteEnd = 0L;
            this.muteCause = "unknown";
            this.muteEnforcer = "unknown";
            updateMuteInfo();
        }
    }
}

public boolean isBanned() {
    return this.banEnd > 0L;
}

public boolean isMuted() {
    return this.muteEnd > 0L;
}

public int getBans() {
    return this.bans;
}

public int getMutes() {
    return this.mutes;
}

public long getBanOn() {
    return banOn;
}

public long getMuteOn() {
    return muteOn;
}

public long getBanEnd() {
    return this.banEnd;
}

public long getMuteEnd() {
    return this.muteEnd;
}

public String getBanCause() {
    return this.banCause;
}

public String getMuteCause() {
    return this.muteCause;
}

public String getBanEnforcer() {
    return this.banEnforcer;
}

public String getMuteEnforcer() {
    return this.muteEnforcer;
}
```

}

Создание объекта класса и заполнение его данными из базы данных само по себе потребляет очень много времени, в связи с чем это сказывается на производительности того места где я создаю этот объект класса.

Comment: Если есть что-то затратное по времени и что при этом можно запустить параллельно с запросом к БД (например, другой запрос к БД по независимым от первого запроса параметрам), то от этого ещё может быть какая-то польза. Потому что смысла в создании отдельного потока с последующим ожиданием результата в основном потоке не видно. А люди, которые советуют, случаем, не аргументировали как-то свой совет?

Comment: @Regent, судя по "все у меня в главном потоке", то это GUI и люди советуют не зря.

Comment: @free_ze я, похоже, привык к тому, что запросы к БД на бэкенде находятся (ибо работаю только с "клиент-сервер"), поэтому даже не подумал, что это может быть в приложении. В этом случае я согласен, что делать что-либо "тяжелое" в GUI потоке не стоит.

Comment: В связи с тем что запрос и ответ от базы данных занимает время(выше которое хотелось бы). 

Нет это не GUI. 

Мне нужно свести задержку запроса и ответа от бд к минимум.

Comment: @ЕвгенийФомин, Если у вас тормозят запросы, то стоило бы заняться их оптимизацией и БД. Потоки/асинхронщина на клиенте поможет лишь для того, чтобы длительные запросы не вешали все остальное.

Comment: @ЕвгенийФомин если вам нужны данные из ответа для продолжения работы, то всё равно придётся ждать ответа, где бы при этом запрос ни выполнялся. А если запрос занимает много времени, то, возможно, проблема в оптимизации запроса или самой БД.

Comment: Добавил немного содержимого в тему.